# How to recover files without extension using PhotoRec

Tags: files, testdisk, photorec

So i had some files without extensions on my usb drive which has been formatted many times.
I tried to use gparted to recover them but no result. Then i found PhotoRec which using deep scan i was able to recover all my files from usb drive (except for those that were without extension). PhotoRec doesn't have an option to recover files without extension and you can't create custom signature which points on files without extension. So i wanted to know, if its somehow possible to recover files without extensions using PhotoRec or any other software or my files are gone forever?

Comment: Photorec doesn't care about extensions, but reads file signatures / magic number.

Comment: ok but i still cannot create custom signature for photorec